# Error no OpenTelemetry when containerd starts . Containerd version 1.6.8

Tags: containerd

INFO[2022-08-31T10:44:23.515904900+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing"...  type=io.containerd.internal.v1
ERRO[2022-08-31T10:44:23.515924646+08:00] failed to initialize a tracing processor "otlp"  error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin"

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue of containerd.
Although the tracing plugin is not loaded, the error message still popped up announcing it failed to init the tracing processor.It doesn't affect the real function of contianerd.
However, it is confusing that it is an error level message.
I've opened an issue for it and created a PR. This issue will be fixed after the PR has been merged.
Refer to: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/7540